# Define a function called avg4. Returns the average of four numbers

Tags: python, function, printing, return

There is a similar question on this website but I found the answers were only for string outputs. e.g dramatically different things. Imagine if I have this python program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def printAndReturnNothing():
    x = "hello"
    print(x)

def printAndReturn():
    x = "hello"
    print(x)
    return x

def main():`enter code here`
    ret = printAndReturn()
    other = printAndReturnNothing()

    print("ret is: %s" % ret)
    print("other is: %s" % other)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What do you expect to be the output?

```
hello
hello
ret is : hello
other is: None
```

However, the question is to define a function called `avg4`. It asks the user for four numbers and returns the average of four numbers. The second question asks to define a function called `avg`. It asks the user for three numbers and prints the average.

Wouldn't these be the same output?

This is my code for `avg4`:

```
def avg4(a,b,c,d):
    a=int(input(ënter a number")
    b
    c
    d
    avg=a+b+c+d/4
    return
```

When I call it it prompts the user to enter four numbers, but doesn't return anything. While the second one, `avg` will print the average.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something using a `return` statement at the end of your `def`. There's also some other changes you needed to make. Your new code would be this:

```
def avg4(): # You don't need parameters for this function; they're overwritten by your input
    a=int(input("Enter a number")) # Added missing quote and bracket
    b=int(input("Enter a second number")) # Filled in inputs for b, c and d
    c=int(input("Enter a third number"))
    d=int(input("Enter a fourth number"))
    avg=(a+b+c+d)/4 # Changed to suit BODMAS
    return avg # Returns the variable avg
```

Now you can do this because `avg` returns something:

```
result = avg()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `avg4` function have several issues. Try to use

```
def avg4():     
    a=int(raw_input("Enter a number").strip())     
    b=int(raw_input("Enter a second number").strip()) 
    c=int(raw_input("Enter a third number").strip())
    d=int(raw_input("Enter a fourth number").strip())
    avg=float(a+b+c+d)/4.0 # avg must be float, not int
    return avg

...
print avg4()
```